# Encryption and Decryption in assembly language

Tags: assembly, encryption, cryptography, intel

I'm try to work on a encryption and decryption problem. You have a file text and you must create 2 algorithms.

First one:

> ```
> Encryption
> -> take every ASCII character from the text file and make the 2's complement
> -> ROR the value with a key C (between 0 and 7)
>
> Decryption
> -> do the reverse for decryption
> ```

Second one:

> ```
> Encryption
> -> take a segment of 10 octets and make the 1's complement
> -> XOR the value with a cryptated key on 64 bytes
> Decryption
> -> do the reverse for decryption .
> ```

I tried to do something but i have no idea if I read the ASCII characters right from the text file. Do i need to use loops for encryption/decryption? Any tips are welcome.

My Code:

```
   .386
   includelib msvcrt.lib
   includelib mylib.asm
   extern printf: proc
   extern fread: proc
   extern fopen: proc
   extern fclose: proc
   extern exit: proc
   public start
   .data
   msg1 DB "Key C (0-7) =",0
   varC DB 0
   formatd DB "%d",0
   formats DB "%s",0
   buffer db 0
   sir db 201 dup(0)
   file_name db "text.txt", 0
   binary_read db "rb", 0
   text dd 0
   .code
        start:

;; key reading
push offset msg1
call printf
add ESP,4
push offset varC
push offset formatd
call scanf
add ESP,8
push offset varC

;; text file reading
call fread
push offset binary_read
push offset file_name
call fopen
add ESP, 8
mov text, EAX
push text
push 200
push 1
push offset sir
call fread
add ESP, 16

;;encryption alg 1
mov ds,ax
mov ax,text
neg ax
ror ax,varC

;;decryption alg 1
ror ax,varC
neg ax
mov ax,fisier
mov ds,ax

push 0
call exit
end start
```

Comment: Before you write the code take the time to formulate a plan. Perhaps make some drawings on paper. Then implement and test one portion at a time.

Comment: ASCII is generally just bytes (I don't think they will be as obnoxious and use 7 bits per character). If you have a sentence like *for every* or when the word "segment" is used then yes, you are expected to create a loop. I haven't got any idea what "cryptated" means though.